# Tabs don't show up in the edit suggestion markdown diff

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff

In [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/21104) somebody fixed the code formatting by indenting every line of code with one tab. In the markdown diff of the edit the tab characters are not shown, making it unclear what exact change was suggested there.

The markdown diff should show the tabs with some visible character, like it is done with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in latest, I now substitute tabs with 4 spaces (`&nbsp;`) for diff purposes.

Comment: This might not work when an editor [changes erroneous tabs into spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/27972): it seems the reviewers won't see that change then? (The [original](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c8acaf9a-e921-42cf-89ae-b1efabd9e3f7/view-source) had `4 SPACES <p...` followed by `TAB <a...` which *I think* was changed into `4 SPACES <a...`. I guess there is [no way](http://i.imgur.com/RzyPh.png) for the reviewer to see that? The rejection might still be fine, as 4 spaces make no difference. Given the original I guess either 2 tabs or 8 spaces should have been used.)